# SQL query to count non unique field

Tags: sql-server, count, group-by, unique

I'm trying to figure out how to add a count on the email field in the query on the end but the problem I have is some of the data required is unique i.e. `ID, DateTime` but the email is not which I want a count of. I just can't figure it out how to do it in one SQL line.

e.g. Return:-

```
101, bla, prd, test@test.com, alfred, comp, test, 2015-10-10 10:10:10, 2  <-- count
100, bla, prd, test@test.com, alfred, comp, test, 2015-09-10 10:11:10, 2
099, bla, prd, anoter@email.com, simpson, comp, test, 2014-10-10 10:10:10, 1
098, bla, prd, bla@email.com, henry, comp, test, 2014-05-10 10:10:10, 1
```

Query

```
select TOP 200 
    ID, 
    FromPage, 
    Product, 
    Email, 
    Name, 
    Company, 
    Industry, 
    DateTime, 
    (count code here as EmailTotal)
from InstallEmails
WHERE product like 'prd%' 
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Comment: You need to use a [window function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) - `COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Email)`

Comment: which version of sql server are you using

Comment: Get Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OVER'.

Comment: It works for me, see [this example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/56192/1)

Comment: can you please post the output

Comment: as GarethD mentioned, `COUNT(*) OVER()` will work for you if you have SQL Server 2012.

Comment: online works with fiddle but not with 2012 here.  Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      11.0.3000.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools      11.0.3000.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      6.1.7601.17514
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      9.11.9600.17126
Microsoft .NET Framework      4.0.30319.18408
Operating System      6.1.7601

Comment: I know the issue, the sql server is an earlier version on the remote server.

Comment: any way of doing it without that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or later, you can use a [window function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

```
SELECT  TOP 200 
        ID, 
        FromPage, 
        Product, 
        Email,
        Name, 
        Company, 
        Industry, 
        DateTime, 
        EmailTotal = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Email)
FROM    InstallEmails
WHERE   product like 'prd%' 
ORDER BY ID DESC;
```

For earlier versions, you will need to use a subquery:

```
SELECT  TOP 200 
        ID, 
        FromPage, 
        Product, 
        Email,
        Name, 
        Company, 
        Industry, 
        DateTime, 
        EmailTotal = (  SELECT  COUNT(*) 
                        FROM    (   SELECT  TOP 200 Email
                                    FROM    InstallEmails
                                    WHERE   product like 'prd%' 
                                    ORDER BY id DESC
                                ) AS ie2
                        WHERE   ie2.Email = ie.Email
                    )
FROM    InstallEmails AS ie
WHERE   product like 'prd%' 
ORDER BY ID DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

worked it out.. appears to be ok.

```
select TOP 200 *,  (select COUNT(email) from InstallEmails where email = t.email) as EmailTotal
from InstallEmails as t
where product like 'prd%' 
ORDER BY ID DESC
```